# edit the package navigation

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !
I used `navigation package` in my robot , but now I want to modify some code in the `base_local_planner` of `navigation` . I know that I cannot edit the source file install in `/opt/ros/hydro/share` , so I downloaded package [here](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=hydro&name=navigation) .

Before I edit the code , I ran my simulation robot in `rviz` and give a `2D navigation` to it . I ran the `$rospack find move_base` to ensure that it link to the package I have download , and it shows `/home/llm/chaoying/src/navigation-hydro-devel.2/move_base` . But the robot went a wrong way and can not arrive the goal which is not same when I used the original `move_base` in `/opt/ros/hydro/share` .
I want to know why ? Are the two package's code different ?

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190790/edit-the-package-navigation/) by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have downloaded and compiled the code from github (https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation) and used the default branch (hydro-devel) the code should be the same.

It is hard to tell what your problem is from your description and pictures. Things to check: 1) Is the robot properly localized? 2) Does the global path go directly to your goal?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-23**:
I have solved this problem , thank you for your advice !